# How to remove both positive and negative numbers from a list in dataframe?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I have a dataframe which contains two list, how to drop both positive and negative number from the lists?
Here is my data: https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/similarity.csv

Input: [0, hi. hello, okay, -3]

Expected output: [hi, hello, okay]

Comment: but 0 isn't positive or negative

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @luigigi, it should remove all the integer values

Comment: new_list= [value for value in old_list if not isinstance(value, str)]

Comment: are you sure? in your data the numbers are strings

Comment: no_integers = [x for x in mylist if not (x.isdigit() 
                                         or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())], i found this on stack overflow too, tried this on, but i am not getting output for negative values. @rossum

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to remove the integers from the start of the `Model1_list` and `Model2_list` columns?  If this is the case, you might find Python's `ast.literal_eval()` function useful. This can take the strings for those columns and convert them into Python lists. It is then a simple case of choosing which parts of the list you want, for example skip the first entry using `[1:]`.

For example:

```py
from ast import literal_eval 
import csv

with open('similarity.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        model1_list = literal_eval(row['Model1_list'])[1:]
        model2_list = literal_eval(row['Model2_list'])[1:]
        
        print(f"{row['Name_1']:40} {str(model1_list):50} {model2_list}")
```

This converts the two model list columns into Python lists and displays them:

```
-1_gun_dont_protect_like                 ['gun', 'dont', 'protect', 'like']                 ['gun', 'peopl', 'right', 'get']
0_http_tco_freenrent_nhttp               ['http', 'tco', 'freenrent', 'nhttp']              ['school', 'children', 'teacher', 'kid']
1_kavanaugh_brett_kill_near              ['kavanaugh', 'brett', 'kill', 'near']             ['http', 'tco', 'freenrent', 'statehoodpr']
2_democrat_strategist_republican_care    ['democrat', 'strategist', 'republican', 'care']   ['idiot', 'stupid', 'your', 'moron']
3_republican_democrat_gun_control        ['republican', 'democrat', 'gun', 'control']       ['suprem', 'court', 'justic', 'assassin']
4_liber_leftist_left_riot                ['liber', 'leftist', 'left', 'riot']               ['weapon', 'gun', 'assault', 'buy']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use python's built-in `lstrip` to remove the plus or minus at the start and check if it's numeric using the `isnumeric` method.

```py
lst = ["0", "hi", "hello", "okay", "-3"]
is_num = lambda s : not s.lstrip('+-').isnumeric()
print(list(filter(is_num, lst))) # or [x for x in lst if is_num(x)]
# output : ['hi', 'hello', 'okay']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with exception handling

```py
def is_int(x):
    try:
        int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

input_ = [0, "hi", "hello", "okay", -3]
out = [i for i in input_ if not is_int(i)]
```